# How to Edit a VisualElementsManifest.xml with a PowerShell Script?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have looked at quite a few posts like [this one](http://sorastog.blogspot.com/2014/05/update-xml-file-using-powershell.html) on how to edit XML files with PowerShell, however, I cannot get any of the solutions to work in my case (I have only a little experience with PowerShell and scripting).

I want to edit `Windows Store.VisualElementsManifest.xml` located in `C:\ProgramData\TileIconify\Windows Store` to change it from this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" GeneratedByTileIconifier="true">
  <VisualElements ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on" Square150x150Logo="VisualElements\MediumIconWindows Store.png" Square70x70Logo="VisualElements\SmallIconWindows Store.png" ForegroundText="dark" BackgroundColor="#41413D" TileIconifierColorSelection="Default" TileIconifierCreatedWithUpgrade="true" />
</Application>
```

to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" GeneratedByTileIconifier="true">
  <VisualElements ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on" Square150x150Logo="VisualElements\MediumIconWindows Store Dark.png" Square70x70Logo="VisualElements\SmallIconWindows Store Dark.png" ForegroundText="dark" BackgroundColor="#41413D" TileIconifierColorSelection="Default" TileIconifierCreatedWithUpgrade="true" />
</Application>
```

I am getting confused because of the fact that the strings in the VisualManifest.xml files are full of quotes and spaces, which break the PowerShell scripts, and none of the threads I have read explain how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking to update 2 properties of your XML, `Square150x150Logo` and `Square70x70Logo`, if that's the case you could try this:

```bash
$filePath = 'Path\to\Windows Store.VisualElementsManifest.xml'
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load($filePath)
$visualElements = $xml.Application.VisualElements
$visualElements.Square150x150Logo = "VisualElements\MediumIconWindows Store Dark.png"
$visualElements.Square70x70Logo   = "VisualElements\SmallIconWindows Store Dark.png"
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: This script works, but I need to edit the original XML instead of creating a new test.xml file.

Comment: @Audio.Anchorite it was there just to show an example of how it works. If the file already exists you just need to use the path of the Xml. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, this actually taught me a lot that will be useful in the future!